# Android Kotlin handling exceptions on ui thread with anko doAsync

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I am new to Kotlin and I have this doAsync with a custom exception handler:

```
doAsync(exceptionHander = {e -> handleException(e)}){
     //rest call
}

 private val handleException= {throwable : Throwable ->
        if(throwable is HttpClientErrorException){
            val response = JSONObject(throwable.responseBodyAsString)
            Toast.makeText(this, response["message"].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

However the Toast is never shown. How can I show this exception message on a Toast? Is the exception handler called on the ui thread?

**Update**:

I have tested this way:

```
doAsync(exceptionHander = {e -> handleException(e)}){
      throw HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "An error has occurred")
}
```

with the same error handler, however the toast won't show.

Comment: Maybe it's a silly question, but are you sure that your exception is an `HttpClientErrorException`?

Comment: Yes, even without the if the toast won't show.

Comment: Do you get any exception in the LogCat? Where is the exceptionHandler run, in the main thread or in a background thread?

Comment: Yes, I got an exception in LogCat. I am not sure if the exception handler runs in the main or backgruond thread. That was part of the question 

Comment: If you have an exception in the LogCat it's always a good idea to post it together with the code, to have a quicker and more accurate answer. Could you please paste it, if you still have the issue?

Comment: I do not have muy laptop with me I will update the question as soon as I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the exception handler is called in a background thread, I used a `try-catch` in the `doAsync` bloc.

```
doAsync{
     var exception: Exception? = null
     try {
          //rest call
     }
     catch(e: HttpClientErrorException){
          exception = e
     }
     uiThread {
        if (exception != null){
             // Show the exception message. 
        }
        else {
             // Update the UI with the result
        }
     }
}
```

So this way one can handle the expected exception on the UI thread. Feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 4):

I'm also think that unexpected exceptions should NOT be ignored (or just logged). But it is not very convenient to add try-canth block every time you use `doAsync`. I created folowing utility function:

```
fun <T> T.doAsyncThrowOnUI(task: AnkoAsyncContext<T>.() -> Unit) = doAsync(
        exceptionHandler = { thr -> Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post { throw thr }},
        task = task)
```

It just calls Anko's `doSync` and passes exception handler that re-throws all unhandled exceptions on UI thread. Use `doAsyncThrowOnUI` in place of Anko's `doAsync`.

```
doAsyncThrowOnUI {
     // do something on bg thread (exceptions rethrown on ui thread)

     uiThread {
        // do something on ui thread
     }
}
```